# What does this db assembly statement mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I am editing a project in assembly language and there is a line in data segment:

```
buffer1 db 80, 0, 80 dup(0)
```

Can somebody elaborate it please?

Comment: db data byte, dw data word, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DB` pseudo instruction allocates memory for data and initializes it with the given values. You can specify consecutive values by separating them with commas. So `DB 5` will allocate a single byte and set its value to `5` and `DB 4, 3` will allocate 2 bytes and set their value to 4 and 3.

`X DUP(V)` will duplicate V X times, so `2 DUP(4)` is like `4, 4`.

Combining those, we get `DB 80, 0, 80 DUP(0)` is like `DB 80, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...`
which will allocate 82 bytes, the first initialized to 80 and the rest to 0.

the prefix, `buffer1` is the buffer *label*, which allows you to refer to the buffer from other places in your code.

This line is loosely equal to the C code:

```
char buffer1[] = {
    80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0
};
```

Or, even simpler:

```
char buffer1[82] = { 80, 0 };
```

Comment: That's probably a buffer used to read in a line from the console in MSDOS,  int 21h with register AH = 0AH, or the old C conio.h function cgets(). The first byte is the size of the buffer (in this case 80 bytes), and the second byte is the returned actual number of bytes input by the user. The rest of the bytes are the input from the user.